# reshaping input layer before passing to model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to combine CNN with attention networks. I have a rather unusual requirement or it might be because I have not understood keras functionality properly. I have a source code from GitHub which I am trying to modify. A section of code is below:-

```
    texts_in = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQ_LEN,config.doc_size), dtype='int32')

    attention_weighted_sentences = TimeDistributed(attention_weighted_sentence)(texts_in)


    if rnn_type is 'GRU':
            #sentence_encoder = Bidirectional(GRU(50, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.2))(attention_weighted_sentences)
            dropout = Dropout(0.1)(attention_weighted_sentences)
            sentence_encoder = Bidirectional(GRU(50, return_sequences=True))(dropout)
    else:
            sentence_encoder = Bidirectional(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.2))(attention_weighted_sentences)


    dense_transform_sentence = Dense(
            100, 
            activation='relu', 
            name='dense_transform_sentence',
            kernel_regularizer=l2_reg)(sentence_encoder)

        # sentence attention
    attention_weighted_text = Attention(name="sentence_attention")(dense_transform_sentence)

    out = Dense(
        data.documents.target_dim, init=my_init,
        W_regularizer=W_regularizer(config),
        activation='sigmoid'
        )(attention_weighted_text)

    # prediction = Dense(19, activation='sigmoid')(attention_weighted_text)       
    # texts_in = Reshape((500,))(texts_in) 
    model = Model(input = texts_in, output= out)
    model.summary()
```

The value of MAX_SEQ_LEN is 1 and config.doc_size is 500 in input layer i.e. texts_in. The reason I have kept the former value as 1 is because I want to reshape the input to (None,500) and don't want input as (None,1,500).

However, since Timedistributed Layer does not take only 2 dims as input so I have to initialize it with (1,500). Is there anyway to reshape the input before passing to the model. Right now, if I reshape the input before passing to model, I get graph disconnected error which is fairly understandable.

However, as I stated I want only 2 dimension for input layer which is None and 500. Can it be done and passed to TimeDistributed Layer or reshaped later?

Comment: I am running out of ideas here. Does no one have any suggestions?